# Links in e-mails are not properly formatted

Tags: emails

I have a site where users can register and login. But in link 70% of the cases the accountVerification e-mail is not sent properly, resulting in users can't verify their account and thus can't login. They all get an Exception page when visiting the link. Below is the not properly formatted link (mark the “id” part):

`/actions/users/setpassword/?code=5QJ_3LUkVKkUpX2OVJITkFScUzYFxjnC&id;=49d83ace-1b12-45fa-a24a-9882c0027321`

The error in the logs is like this one:

`[exception.Craft\HttpException.400] exception 'Craft\HttpException' with message 'Parameter "id" bestaat niet.' in /home/xxxxxx/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php:586`

I can’t seem to find a solution for this and actually expect I can’t be the only one with this problem. In the e-mail I'm already giving the users two links to verify their account, one normal `{{ link }}` tag and an `{{ link | escape }}` tag. But it still doesn’t work. Maybe anyone of you can help me? Would be great, thanks!

Comment: The issue is a stray semicolon is getting inserted after the id param?  Weird... first time I've seen that. If you go to yourdomain.com/admin/utils/phpinfo and search for `arg_separator.output`, what's the value set to?